# Array of custom classes changing when a different array of classes updated java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

So my code is this: http://pastebin.com/6btewXRB.
What I do in the main code is I set the hand variable, and then call Update. What happens, is whenever I update 'thinkingHand', then 'oldoldThinkingHand' gets updated despite being different. If there are any other mistakes, please let me know.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Your `update` method is resetting both `thinkingHand` and `oldoldThinkingHand` with same `hand`.